# Can you help improve the writing of my proof of $\sin \arctan x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing

In order to improve my proof writing, I proved a well established, but less frequently encountered, identity (whose proof is Spivak Problem 15.16).

Is the proof rigorous? Did I handle the issue of different quadrants (plus/minus) correctly? Is the exposition clear (while still succinct)? How could it be improved?

All feedback and suggestions are in scope.

*Note: Proofs of this identity of course exist.  This question is about proof writing and how to write **this** proof.*

---

**Proposition:** For all $x$, $$\sin \arctan x = \pm \frac x {\sqrt{1+x^2}} \\ \cos \arctan x = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$

**Proof:** Let $$t = \pm \frac x {\sqrt {1 + x^2}}$$ so $$\sqrt{1-t^2} = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \\ x = \frac t {\sqrt {1 - t^2}}.$$

Since $t^2 + (\sqrt{1 - t^2})^2 = 1$, there exists an $\alpha \in (- \frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ such that $$t = \sin \alpha \\ \sqrt{1 - t^2} = \cos \alpha \\ x = \tan \alpha$$ which completes the proof.

Comment: In fact you can drop the $\pm$ signs. If $x>0$ then $0<\arctan x<\pi/2$ so $0<\sin x<1$, i.e. $\sin\arctan x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. That the function is odd handles the case $x<0$. Similarly, $\cos\arctan x=\sin\arctan x/\underbrace{\tan\arctan x}_x$.

Comment: @J.G. Interesting.  Is that why we define $\arctan$ over $(-\pi/2, \pi,2)$ and not $(0, \pi)$? I always wondered why we did that.... But I see now it has the advantage of making $\cos \arctan x$ positive for all $x$, as you describe.  (Or would we get the same result if we used $(0, \pi)$ making $\sin \arctan x$ always positive?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in a comment, the $\pm$ symbols are entirely unnecessary, and somewhat confusing.

Why would we define $t$ using two different values for a given $x$? Do we need to prove anything is true for both values of $t$?

In the step

$$ \sqrt{1-t^2} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

the equation is only true with a $+$ sign, and can't be true with a $-$ sign, since a $\sqrt{a}$ value is never negative and the right side is clearly not zero.

Simply remove every $\pm$ symbol from your entire proof, and it's more correct and easier to follow. (It's not among the simplest proofs, but I think it's fine.)

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks fine, assuming positive signs as noticed, as an alternative let $x=\tan \alpha$ with $\alpha \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ then

- $\sin \arctan x = \sin \alpha$
- $\frac x {\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sin \alpha$
- $\cos \arctan x = \cos \alpha$
- $\frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}}= \cos \alpha$

Comment: How have you proven the second and fourth bullet points?

Comment: @SRobertJames By basic identities $$1+\tan^2 \alpha=\frac{\cos^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \alpha}{\cos^2 \alpha}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 \alpha}$$